# Serverless Lambda Resource Based Policy - All Principles

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I am trying to define in the serverless YAML file with a resource based policy that ** allows any rule from EventBridge ** to invoke the function; this is due to in my application, EventBridge rules are dynamically generated.

In the AWS's console, it does not allow create a Lambda permission's EventBridge with wildcard.

The following was my attempt but it did not generate any resource policy when deployed:

```
provider:
  resourcePolicy: ${self:custom.resourcePolicies.test}

... other things

custom:
  resourcePolicies:
    test:
      - Effect: Allow
        Principal: "*"
        Action: lambda:InvokeFunction

... other things
```

Guidance appreciated.

Comment: " it did not work" - is not  specific. What exactly happened? Error messages?

Comment: For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Marcin thanks for your comment. The issue has been refined.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thanks for your comment. The issue has been refined.

Comment: @Jim_Mcdonalds hi! have you been able to figure it out?

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer in [this](https://forum.serverless.com/t/how-to-set-up-a-lambda-function-for-dynamic-cloudwatch-event-rules/6146/5) post by henhal on serverless forums.

Basically you have to create new resource of `AWS::Lambda::Permission` type.

```
resources:
  Resources:
    InvokeGenerateReportLambda:
      Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
      Properties:
        Action: lambda:invokeFunction
        FunctionName: ${env:LAMBDA_FUNCTION_ARN}
        Principal: events.amazonaws.com
        SourceArn: ${env:RULE_ARN} #can include wildcards
```